# how the query works, select any name ends with %

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch all names ends with a % at the end.

My query is working but don't know how:-

```
1. select name from table where name like '%\%%'

2. select name from table where name like '%%\%'
```

May i know how this query works and difference? the backslash position not matters, how?

please help:-

Comment: The first one will find folks that have a `%` in any position. The second will find folks that end in `%`. To wrap your head around it, just change `/%` to some other character like `%,%` vs `%%,`. You can see that second one has a redundant `%` to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are confused about is the `%` as a wildcard.  It can match any number of characters -- or none.

So, you want:

```
where name like '%\%'
```

The two wildcards together (`%%`) are the same as one.  The first version will match something with `%` in the middle of the string.

Or, alternatively:

```
where right(name, 1) = '%'  -- less confusing
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so can i give like where name like '%\%' only no?why '%%\%' used for?also why this slash for?

Comment: @youv . . . The slash is the default escape character for `like` so the `%` matches `%` and is not a wildcard.